# Errors when including intrin.h?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to build my project, which uses things like `__cpuid` and `__cpuidex`, so I need intrin.h. When I try to include it and build my project, I get two errors. They are:

```
`tagMENUBARINFO::fUnused`: type of bit field too small for number of bits
```

in winuser.h, and in minwindef.h I get the error

```
`BOOL`: redefinition; different basic types
```

My includes:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <intrin.h>
```

I need all of these includes, so removing some isn't really an option.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 as my compiler, my Windows SDK Version is 10.0, and the C++ language standard is ISO C++14 Standard.

Comment: Are those your only includes, or are you including other headers before windows.h?

Comment: Compiles clean for me, live https://godbolt.org/z/cPj3nq

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm those are my only includes in the header file. The only thing before it is `#pragma once` , and the header isnt included by anything except for it's cpp file which has no includes of it's own.

Comment: You might have something not installed correctly, or have bad include paths. My WinUser.h (that defines the MENUBARINFO struct; in windows kits 10.0.18362.0) does not have member named `fUnused` in the struct definition. Is there any more to the error messages, particularly the `BOOL` redefinition (like where the first definition is)? Are full paths to header files included in the messages?